# How to locate a Kendo UI detailGrid after create complete event

Tags: events, grid, kendo-ui

I'm sorry to ask this question because it seems like the answer should be obvious, but I can't find it.

I am processing the "complete" event after a create action on a detail grid because I wish to refresh the grid after the insert. But I can't find a sensible way to it. Here is what I have done. I am doing it all in HTML and JavaScript. When the detail grid is initialized, I "name: it 'panegrid' suffixed by the key of the master record. Like below:

```
   function detailInit(e) {
       if (e.data.Id != '') { // Must be a Create for Lite so don't create a grid
           $("<div id='panegrid" + e.data.Id + "' />").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
               dataSource: {
```

And then when the create completes I find the grid like this:

```
complete: function (e) {
    var selector = '#panegrid' + $.parseJSON(e.responseText).IGUnit_Id;
    $(selector).data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
 }
```

This works (IGUnit_Id is the primary key of the Master Grid), but it just doesn't seem right to have to do it this way. Surely there is some "correct way" to find the grid from within the complete event directly without playing around with selectors.

I appreciate your help and apologize for asking such a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a reference to a grid when you create it, simply assign a variable to it and append `.data('kendoGrid')` to your create expression, e.g.

```
var myGrid = $("<div id='panegrid" + e.data.Id + "' />").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        // etc...
    }
}).data('kendoGrid');
```

Then later

```
myGrid.dataSource.read();
```

Of course, you wouldn't want it to be a local variable, you would need to add it as a property of something visible from the rest of your code, but I leave that exercise up to you.